# SQL: Select * where start and end falls within two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, between

I have a `tasks` table as such:

```
+-------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| rowid | title             | start_task          | due_date            |
+-------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1     | Paint Apartment   | 2018-03-01 07:00:00 | 2018-03-16 15:00:00 |
+-------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2     | Meeting with John | 2018-03-10 10:00:00 | 2018-03-10 12:30:00 |
+-------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 3     | Buy Milk          | 2018-03-04 20:00:00 | NULL                |
+-------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 4     | Renew Rail Card   | NULL                | 2018-03-07 09:00:00 |
+-------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And I want to select everything for the week `2018-03-05` to `2018-03-11` so it should print rows 1,2 & 4.

So my query should include the following:

1. Everything that starts between 2018-03-05 and 2018-03-11
2. Everything that is due between 2018-03-05 and 2018-03-11
3. Everything that the period of start_task and due_date falls within 2018-03-05 and 2018-03-11

My current SQL that does 1 and 2 and prints rows 2 & 4:

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` tasks where ((`start_task` >= '2018-03-05 00:00:00' and `start_task` <= '2018-03-11 23:59:59') OR (`due_date` >= '2018-03-05 00:00:00' and `due_date` <= '2018-03-11 23:59:59'))
```

Comment: @barmar how is this a duplicate or overlapping date ranges?

Comment: @barmar The answers in the duplicated question you marked does not answer my question. In 2 minutes you havent even read my question and you marked it as duplicated.

Comment: I thought you wanted to check if the range between start_task and due_date includes the range 2018-03-05 to 2018-03-11.

Comment: @Barmar You're assigning duplicated questions based on your first thought without even reading the content?

Comment: Can you give an example of something that meets criteria 3 but not 1 or 2?

Comment: I read the question. Your description is not very clear, but I thought I understood it to be the same as the other. I've reopened, OK?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are just missing anything where the start - due date period spans the week you are checking?  This should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `tasks` tasks 
WHERE 
    (
        (`start_task` >= '2018-03-05 00:00:00' and `start_task` <= '2018-03-11 23:59:59') 
        OR (`due_date` >= '2018-03-05 00:00:00' and `due_date` <= '2018-03-11 23:59:59')
        OR (`start_task` <= '2018-03-11 23:59:59' and `due_date` >= '2018-03-05 00:00:00')
    )
```

As has been mentioned this can also be reduced to a single test:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `tasks` tasks 
WHERE
    COALESCE(`start_task`, '2018-03-11 23:59:59') <= '2018-03-11 23:59:59' 
    AND COALESCE(`due_date`, '2018-03-05 00:00:00') >= '2018-03-05 00:00:00'
```

I think that's the right syntax for MySQL, apologies if it isn't.  Note that this would also mean that a `NULL` start date AND a `NULL` due date would be a pass, when you might want that to be a fail?

Comment: Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts. That's the only comparison that needs to be considered. The rest is noise.

Comment: Apart from the fact that NULLs are involved.  I was going to add an edit to show how this could be reduced to a single test using COALESCE to handle the NULL cases, but my MySQL isn't fantastic...

Answer (score 2):

You are checking for a non-empty intersection between two intervals (`start_date` ➔ `due_date` and Mar 05 ➔ Mar 11).

You can do this with:

```
select *
  from `tasks` tasks
 where (`start_task` is null or `start_task` <= '2018-03-11 23:59:59') -- start <= end
   and (`due_date`   is null or `due_date`   >= '2018-03-05 00:00:00') -- end   >= start
```

*(assuming `null` start/end date means unbounded interval)*

Remember it as: "each interval must start before the other ends".

---

To better understand why, think of the inverse problem.

In order for two intervals to have an empty intersection you must either have `interval 2` end before `interval 1` starts:

```
interval 1: --------(---)--------
interval 2: -(---)---------------
```

or `interval 2` start after `interval 1` ends:

```
interval 1: --------(---)--------
interval 2: ---------------(---)-
```

Negate the conjunction of these two conditions and apply De Morgan to get a condition for non-empty intersection.